# Unique single value for a 3D point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, floating-point

I have 3D points like this:

```
Vertex {
    X float
    , Y float
    , Z float
}
```

Is there any *single* value of type `float` or `int` which is unique for a 3D point and is a function of `X`, `Y` and `Z`?

Comment: You want a bijective map $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$? The inverse map is a curve, realized by a  computer algorithm this is generally one-dimensional and does not fill the space.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks =) So, is it *not* possible?

Comment: You could of course do some bit-manipulations to splice the mantissas and exponents together, but that is then hardly an analytical map. However, continuous space-filling curves exist. But maybe your purpose is already served with some kind of hash map?

Comment: @LutzLehmann That's exactly right! I was looking for an easy hash map!

Comment: This then depends on the density and range of the points that you expect to inventory. For instance, you could just take the leading 8 mantissa bits and concatenate them into a 32 bit integer. This will of course produce collisions if the range of the numbers is large enough or if they are dense enough that more mantissa bits are necessary to distinguish them.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! My original problem is [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62358008/3405291) which triggered me to ask this question =)